# Why would I use an SSIS package in SQL Server 2008 as opposed to some other technology?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, meta

I'm in a QA department of an internal development group. Our production database programmers have been building an SSIS package to create a load file from various database bits for import into a third-party application (we are testing integration with this).

Once built, it was quickly discovered that it had dependencies on the version of SQL Server and Visual Studio that it was created with, and had quite of few dependencies on the production environment as well (this is not an SSIS problem, just describing the nature of our setup).

Getting this built took several days of solid effort, and then would not run under our QA environment.

After asking that team for the SQL queries that their package was running (it works fine in the production environment), I wrote a python script that performed the same task without any dependencies. It took me a little over two hours (note that I already had a custom library for handling our database interaction), and I was able to write out a UTF-16LE file that I needed.

Now, our production database programmers are not SSIS experts, but they use it a fair bit in their workflows -- I would readily call all of them competent in their positions.

Thus, my question -- given the time it appears to take and the dependencies on the versions of SQL Server and Visual Studio, what advantage or benefits does an SSIS package bring that I may not see with my python code? Or a shell script, or Ruby or code-flavor-of-the-moment?

Comment: One dev might want to use Python, another Ruby, a third one Perl - how is that better than having all of them using SSIS which is a) designed for these kinds of jobs (ETL - loading, transforming data in large volumes) and b) part of SQL Server and requires no additional dependencies (like a Python interpreter/runtime et. al.) ?

Comment: That's sorta my question - what makes SSIS compelling over your-favorite-language?

Comment: Mostly: (1) it's already part of SQL Server - no additional installation needed (no Python interpreter or runtime), and (2) it's geared and tooled towards ETL processes - has tasks and components that you'd have to potentially write lots of Python code for all things about loading and transforming data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not an expert in SSIS by any means but an average developer who has experience working with SSIS for little over three years. Like any other software, there are short comings with SSIS as well but so far I have enjoyed working with SSIS. Selection of technology depends on one's requirement and preferences. I am not going to say SSIS is superior over other technologies. Also, I have not worked with Python, Ruby or other technologies that you have mentioned.

Here are my two cents. Please take this with a grain of salt.

1. From an average developer point of view, SSIS is easy to use once you understand the nuances of how to handle it. I believe that the same is true for any other technology. SSIS packages are visual work flows rather than a coding tool (of course, SSIS has excellent coding capabilities too). One can easily understand what is going on within a package by looking at the work flows instead of going through hundreds of lines of code.
2. SSIS is built mainly to perform ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) jobs. It is fine tuned to handle that functionality really well especially with SQL Server and not to mention that it can handle flat files, DB2, Oracle and other data sources as well.
3. You can perform most of the tasks with minimal or no coding. It can load millions of rows from one data source to another within few minutes. [**See this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061075/sql-integration-services-to-load-tab-delimited-file/6159600#6159600) demonstrating a package that loads a million rows from tab delimited file into SQL Server within **3 minutes**.
4. `Logging` capabilities to capture every action performed by the package and its tasks. It helps to pinpoint the errors or track information about the actions performed by the package. This requires no coding. [**See this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122773/check-the-result-after-ssis-job-has-completed/6123867#6123867) for logging.
5. `Check Points` help to capture the package execution like a recorder and assists in restarting the package execution from the point of failure instead of running the package from the beginning.
6. `Expressions` can be used to determine the package flow depending on a given condition.
7. `Package configurations` can be set up for different environments using database or XML based `dtsconfig` files or Machine based Environment variables. [**See this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180378/ssis-best-practices-when-handling-files-can-i-go-configless/6191808#6191808) for Environment Variables based configuration. Points #4 - #7 are out-of-the-box features which require minor configuration and requires no coding at all.
8. SSIS can leverage the .NET framework capabilities and also developers can create their own custom components if they can't find a component that meets their requirement. [**See this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231414/how-to-load-a-flat-file-with-header-and-detail-parent-child-relationship-into-sql/6240302#6240302) to understand how .NET coding can be best used along with different data source. This example was created in less than `3 hours`.
9. SSIS can use the same data source for multiple transformations without having to re-read the data. [**See this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213847/using-multi-cast-transformation-for-destinations-with-different-columns/6213990#6213990) to understand what Multicasting means. Here is [**an example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152671/mapping-an-xml-file-to-a-database-with-ssis/6222777#6222777) of how XML data sources can be handled.
10. SSIS can also integrate with **SSRS** (Reporting Services) and **SSAS** (Analysis Services) easily.

I have just listed very basic things that I have used in SSIS but there are lot of nice features. As I mentioned earlier, I am not sure if Python, Ruby or other languages can handle these tasks with such ease.

It all boils down to one's comfort with the technology. When the technology is new, people are very much skeptical and unwilling to adapt it.

In my experience, once you understand and embrace SSIS it is really a nice technology to use. It works really well with SQL Server. I don't deny the fact that I faced obstacles during development of my packages but mostly found a way to overcome them.

This may not be the answer that you were expecting but I hope this gives an idea.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.  I have had little contact with SSIS, and was wondering if it were an appropriate solution for our needs, or just the hammer of choice for our production DB programmers.

Comment: Great answer.  I'd add that many developers reach for SSIS when a simple SQL query and job will do just fine.